# Should we be updating aptitude answers

Tags: discussion

There are quite a number of answers telling people to install software using aptitude. However it is not installed by default in 10.10 which may confuse people trying to follow the instructions.

Should we be migrating existing answers which include aptitude commands to apt-get?

Comment: Here's some background: http://askubuntu.com/questions/29660/why-was-aptitude-removed-in-favor-of-apt-get

Answer (score 4):

It's not as easy as a blanket search and replace because there are some answers that use the more advanced querying features of `aptitude`.

But if you type `aptitude` into a system that doesn't have it installed, it will tell you how to install it. That should circumvent any major confusion.

I personally don't think it's worth it. There is lower hanging fruit lying around here that needs more urgent attention than the odd edit. But I wouldn't reject an edit that swapped `aptitude` for `apt-get` (unless it were syntactically incorrect, of course).

Comment: I think that's fair enough.   I'd almost rather edits just add the `apt-get` info rather than just swapping out with `aptitude`.  I think it's fine to have aptitude there, just not as the only answer for beginners.

Comment: When i mention `aptitude` in the questions and mention how to install it in many of the cases but i am one of the users that would really like to have aptitude back for the simplicity and the friendlier that it is versus apt.